# In Python, do objects have their own copies of class variables?

Tags: python, class, object, variables, copy

This is a question which confuses every Python Intermediate learner, so please give a brief (and idiot-friendly) answer.

I wanted to create a variable which increments the variable `population` by 1 when a new object is created.

```
class Human:

    population = 0

    # initialization.
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    
    def increment_pop(self):
        self.population += 1

# class Human ends.

person = Human('Tom', 22, 'M')
person.increment_pop()
person.increment_pop()
print('Population : ', person.population)

person2 = Human('Anna', 24, 'F')
person2.increment_pop()
print('Population : ', person2.population)

print(Human.population)
```

Output :

```
Population :  2
Population :  1
0
```

So both the object and the class has the variable `population`? What is the difference between the variable `population` and the variables inside the **init**() method?

I know that only instance variables are inside the **init**() method.

Comment: `self.population += 1` is assigning to `self.population`, not to `Human.population`, so it creates an instance variable separate from the class variable.

Comment: I mean, you answered your own question. One is a class variable (sometimes called static variable in other languages), the other is an instance variable, which is distinct to every instance of the class. To get the desired effect, you would increment `Human.population`, rather than `self.population`.

Comment: If I call `self.population` and it's creating a separate instance variable, how does it initialize before incrementing itself? That is, how does it choose a specific value to initialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complex than that. There are both class variables and instance variables, but what's happening in your example is that the class variable is being *overridden* by the instance variable.

Consider the following:

```py
>>> class Foobar:
...     my_list = []
... 
>>> foo = Foobar()
>>> Foobar.my_list.append('hello')
>>> foo.my_list.append('world')
>>> foo.my_list
['hello', 'world']
```

As you can see the `Foobar` class and `foo` instance *share a variable here*. So no, instantiating a class does not "copy" all the class variables. Consider this, however:

```
>>> foo.my_list = ['spam', 'eggs']
>>> foo.my_list
['spam', 'eggs']
>>> Foobar.my_list
['hello', 'world']
```

Now we have *two variables*, one that's a class variable, the other that's an instance variable. They are no longer the same.

If you wanted to always use class variables, the most elegant thing would be to use class methods. Eg,

```
class Human:

    population = 0

    # initialization.
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    @classmethod
    def increment_pop(cls):
        cls.population += 1
```

Now because `increment_pop` is a class method, it will always operate on the class, not the instance. However, the `population` attribute will be available to instances and as long as they don't overwrite it, it will be the *same* as the class variable.

A few important things to keep in mind:

1. Primitives, like integers and strings, are immutable. When you do `foo += 1`, you're creating a new instance of an integer and replacing the old one. You're not modifying it in place.
2. Instances can access class variables and class methods with `self.whatnot`. But if you want to be unambiguous, you can also reference them as `ClassName.whatnot`.
3. Class methods can be called from instances, similarly, like `self.class_method()`.

## Other notes on Python variables

Let's back up here and consider how Python resolves a request for something like `my_human.population` on the *instance*:

1. First, Python looks for an instance attribute named `population`. If it exists, that's the value you get.
2. **Second**, Python looks for a class attribute named `population`. If that exists, that's the value you get.

So, when you have no assigned `population` on your instance, and you access `self.population`, since no instance attribute exists with that name, you get the class attribute.

However, once you assign an instance attribute to your object, that second step above never happens.

You can inspect this at runtime, too:

```py
>>> class Human:
...     population = 0
...
>>> my_human = Human()
>>> 'population' in Human.__dict__
True
>>> 'population' in my_human.__dict__
False
```

So `population` **only exists** on the Human class, not on the instance. When we access `Human.population`, it finds the class attribute:

```py
>>> my_human.population
0
```

But what happens if I *create an instance* attribute?

```
>>> Human.population = 100
>>> my_human.population = 50
>>> Human.population
100
>>> my_human.population
50
```

Now, because the instance has an attribute matching the name `population`, when you access `my_human.population`, it never looks up what's on the class.

Comment: I'll present my new doubts point by point:

(01) In your first example of code, is the `my_list`variable in the object `foo` just a copy of that present in the class `Foobar` (which we access as `Foobar.my_list`)?
That is, is the variable `my_list`in the object just a reflection of that in the class?

(02) As per the above point, isn't calling a class method inside an instance method unreliable, as it would only change the copy of the class variable?

Comment: Ok, I explained it a little further in the added section, "Other notes on Python variables"

Comment: To your second question, it's not unreliable. Since a classmethod is only modifying the cls object, its behavior is quite predictable. Having said that, it might be good practice (to help make your code readable) NOT to shadow a class variable with an instance variable unless you have a good reason.

Comment: I think you're probably being tripped up by studying both immutables and class variables all at once. Keep in mind that `foo += 1` is sort of like *deleting* the foo variable, then creating a new foo variable with an increment of 1. It creates a new object, so when you create that new object, you're creating it on the instance in your example.

Comment: (01) I was talking about the unreliability of the *shadow* variable.

(02) I didn't understand your last point : "studying both immutables and class variables all at once.". How have you learnt classes in Python (guidance)? What is the relationship?

(03) About your last comment: "Keep in mind that foo += 1 is sort of like deleting the foo variable, then creating a new foo variable with an increment of 1. It creates a new object, so when you create that new object, you're creating it on the instance in your example." Why have you mentioned it here?

Comment: I mean that in your code, you have to (a) understand that primaries are immutable, (b) understand class vs instance attributes. You have to master both those concepts to see what's going on. That's all I mean. So if you were truly modifying a variable *in place*, like what the ++ operator would do in C, you would see different behavior. But Python primitives are always immutable.

Comment: Can you give an example how the ++ operator would give different results in Python?

Comment: There is no ++ operator in Python.

But the point is more that in C, you have pass by value and pass by reference. In Python, there's only pass by reference. If you do x += 1, you're deleting the old reference and creating a new one.

Comment: Is there a way to use this information to our advantage? Also, how do I understand how these variables work in the background (where instance/class/static variables are stored in memory)?

Comment: You can see those variables on the `__dict__` attributes of each class. Eg, `population in Human.__dict__` will be True, but will be False until you set an instance attribute. In terms of practical use, one use might be creating sensible defaults as class attributes, with settings overridden on each instance.

Answer (score 0):

`self` references a specific instance of a class.  When you call increment_pop, you are using self.population, which is causing the increment only of that instance.  Because in python you do not need to call initializers, increment_pop is created a new variable called self.population, where the class variable population should be global.

Change increment_pop to have cls.population rather than self.population and it should work as intended.  Note that in the function definition you'll need the decorator @classmethod and the parameter cls.